# How to recursively delete a dir after find

Tags: find

```
find .   -name "DIR-NAME" -type d -delete
```

because i want to delete specific dir name recursively 
well it returns

```
find: cannot delete `./DIR-NAME': Directory not empty
```

which is expeted but I have no idea how to make -delete to delete non-empty dirs here as i can with rm -rf

Answer (score 8):

Like this :

```
find . -name "DIR-NAME" -type d -exec rm -r {} +
```

Comment: Maybe better as `find . -name DIR-NAME -type d -prune -exec rm -rf {} +`

Comment: As the time that was written, that was not fully supported everywhere ^^ IIRC

Comment: See [find . -print0 | xargs -0 cmd vs find . -exec cmd {} +](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/730873) about history of `-exec {} +`. I'd say it was about as common in 2014 as now. My point was more about `-prune`. Feel free to  include my comment on Andy's answer; it looks like his account is not longer active.

Comment: For the love of god, quote your `{}` arguments, otherwise you have a security issue if someone make a directory with a space it can delete directories outside of the directory and even the root

Answer (score 1):

Before you delete directories, you could delete files. ie first run:

```
find .   -name "DIR-NAME" -type f -delete
```

Might not work if you have special file types.

Comment: Wow, sure missed that argument. I'd suggest then " find .   -name "DIR-NAME" -type d -exec rm -rf  {} ';'" and I'll see myself out.

Comment: ITYM something like `LC_ALL=C find . '(' -path '*/DIR-NAME/*' -o -name DIR-NAME -type d ')' -delete`.