# How to delete the content of all subdirectories named "output"?

Tags: files, find

I downloaded a project from web.When building the project it produces output files in folder named **output**.The problem is there are many folders with same name.I need to manually delete the files in all `output` directories.

I used this command

```
find . -type d -name "output" -print
```

It displays the location of all directories with same name.

Then i used this command

```
find . -type d -name "output" -delete
```

> find: cannot delete ‘./output’: Directory not empty

I don't want to delete the `output` folder I want to delete all the files under the `output` folder name.

Comment: @don_crissti it contains directories and files .i want to delete everything under the output folder.

Comment: [How to recursively delete a dir after find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175674/how-to-recursively-delete-a-dir-after-find) or [How to delete directories based on `find` output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/89925/170373) ?

Comment: @ilkkachu sorry i dont know how to do that thats y asked for help.i learned that find command to delete files so i tried to use it to delete files under  directory also.

Comment: @ilkkachu  thanks for the link. i tried this link [link] (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89925/how-to-delete-directories-based-on-find-output) it completely removes my directory but i need to delete only files or directories contained in it.

Comment: @Jeeva You just changed your spec from deleting all files under the output folder to delete files or directories contained in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `find` has `-mindepth` and `-delete` (at least GNU or BSD):

```
find . -name output -type d -exec find {} -mindepth 1 -delete \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following ways depending on the version of `find` you may have.

GNU find:

```
find . -type f -path '*/output/*' -exec echo rm -f {} \;
```

POSIX-find

```
find . -type d -name output -exec sh -c 'find "$1"/. ! -name . -prune -type f -exec rm -f \{\} \;' {} {} \;
```

Comment: find . -type f -path '*/output/*' -exec echo rm -f {} \; it doesnt work

Comment: Where did you make the `*` vanish around `/output/`? Look at the command again.

Comment: @RakeshSharma excatly wat don said.sorry for the editing part

Comment: Ok then that means your `find` ain't GNU. So need to use the POSIX version then.

Comment: @RakeshSharma Which part of the first command is not POSIX?

Comment: @Kusalananda the `-path` option is non-POSIX.

Comment: @RakeshSharma `-path` is  POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html

Comment: @Kusalananda I need to upgrade my docs. I was referring until now to `http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/find.html` :-/ Thanks for pointing that out.